# PHPMailer File Upload Not Working

Tags: php, forms, file, upload, phpmailer

My Contact form working good but i can't get the uploaded files with contact form. HTML Codes here;

```
<form id="contact_form" method="post" action="php/mail-advanced.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple />
<label for="file"></label>
<button type="submit" id="submit">SEND MESSAGE</button></form>
```

And these code in my php/mail-advanced.php file;

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = "smtp.example.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "noreply@example.com";
$mail->Password = "pass";
$mail->setFrom('noreply@example.com', 'Example Message');
$mail->addReplyTo($email);
$mail->addAddress('example@gmail.com', 'Example Message');
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->addAttachment($_FILES['file']);

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

How i can get files with file uploads on PHPMailer? Thanks!

Comment: look at the $_FILES array again

Comment: Do it properly and safely; follow [the file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps).

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the file's temp name in PHP. It's basically the same way as actually uploading.

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

Comment: This is unsafe. Read [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Comment: I didn't say it safe, just gave a straight answer to his question